# Windows security update KB28544286 cause xsl:stylesheet error message: Unable to display this Web Part

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

Error Message-
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

I have several lists across our entire sharepoint server that have custom xsl:stylesheet's. These are webparts of lists both internally to the site collection and to external data on our sql common data server. The common problem factor in all these webparts is the xsl:stylesheet.

I am getting the error above on all the lists that have some sort of customisation whether it be just a simple text color change or a complex custom layout.

All of these webparts were working great before July 10th when I left for vacation.

When I came back from my vacation I was informed that a specific list was not working and I went to work attempting to figure it out. In order to get it working I simply had to take out the custom xsl:stylesheet. This works, however when I went back to asses the rest of the site today I found that all of the webpart lists that included the custom xsl:stylesheet are not working.

I discovered that there were several server updates on july 10th sent down from Microsoft.

I believe that one of the updates caused this but not sure which one or how to stop this from happening again.

If you have any idea please assist.

Comment: Just to verify, these list webparts do infact work in SharePoint designer. However, they do not work in any browser thus far.

Comment: I found the windows update that caused my issue. Windows security update KB28544286. I have temporarily blocked this update but if there is a better solution I really need to apply something else so this does not happen again. My understanding is that this is the second time Microsoft has issues an update that breaks the xsl:Stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2013/07/ms13-052-causes-issues-with-sharepoint/.  And here is a resolution to the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872441.

Comment: Thank you Trevor, that did resolve part of the issue. I am still having issues with my xsl:stylesheet when I attempt to execute a search on this application. However, it appears that this issue has nothing to do with that particular update. Therefore, It looks like i need to had back to the drawing board and see where that issue stems from. Do you know of any known issues with the July 10th updates?